# how to compute stationary points?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have a function $f(x) = -\frac{1}{6}e^{-x+1}$ and it says that it has stationary points between 0 and 1, but I don’t understand how you know if a function has stationary points or roots between 0 and 1, can someone help?

Comment: Are you sure that $$f(x)=-\frac{1}{6}e^{1-x}$$ is written correctly?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know what stationary points are? Also, it could be that there's a typo in the function. I don't think $e^{1-x}$ it has any stationary points ...

Answer (score 0):

For the given function $f(x)$, differentiating gives $\frac{1}{6}e^{1-x}$ which never equals $0$. Since, stationary points are where the derivative of a function is $0$.

$\therefore \ $$f(x)=-\frac{1}{6}e^{1-x}$ has no stationary points.